# Deploying with Capistrano, JAVA_HOME is not being read

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, environment-variables, capistrano, rjb

I am deploying with Capistrano and everything looked good until I got to Rjb part..

I can do

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64
```

More than that, I can do gem install rjb on server and it is getting installed...

However when I try:

```
$ cap bundle:install
```

I get

```
** [out :: ec-...compute-1.amazonaws.com] extconf.rb:53:in `<main>': JAVA_HOME is not set. (RuntimeError)
```

Comment: Set :default_environment worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capistrano doesn't load the environment variables from the deployer machine or the deploy target; you'll have to specify them in your deploy.rb:

```
set :default_environment, 'JAVA_HOME' => "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64"
```

Comment: Credit goes to Stpn for answering his own question - I'm just placing this in the Answers section.

Comment: I've been trying to use this with capistrano 3 and I keep getting the same error. Have you tried this on Capistrano 3? I've set the env by the new way they specify. `set :default_env, { 'JAVA_HOME' => "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64" }` I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I can install the gem manually on the machine and it works but it doesn't work when running `cap deploy`

Comment: Please post a new question, as this question was for capistrano 2.